# boost::thread hangs before program even starts?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I've set up a new development machine; it's running windows 10 & Visual Studio 2017 community. Installed and built boost (1.64.0, complete build), all good.

I've been using some IPC and everything is good but then I started getting a strange behavior: my programs started to hang at the very start.

I'm dealing with console apps by the way. The program just starts and the cursor blinks as if it was waiting for some user input or if the main thread was sleeping before any output happens. Even though the very first thing all my programs to is to print a header.

After a lot of painful failures trying to identify the problem, I noticed that it only happens when I use any boost.thread functionality. So I thought maybe it's some problem while migrating projects from VS2015 to VS2017; created a brand new project and the same thing happens.

Even when using the simplest of programs (ex. [simple thread example](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.thread-management#ex.thread_01))... all I get is a blinking cursor. No matter if I'm building with debug or release profiles and even if try to debug.

VS never arrives at any break point (even when starting the program with the "step into" command!). The "hanging" seems to happen before my code's entry point.

So I hope the question is clear: "what the *bleep* is going on?"

As mentioned: other boost libraries are working fine, including boost::locale and boost::chrono

--edit: compiles fine, no warnings. Runs "seemingly" fine, no errors and doesn't terminate, just hangs there as if the main thread was sleeping.

--edit 2: full code example:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <iostream>

void wait(int seconds)
{
  boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds{seconds});
}

void thread()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  {
    wait(1);
    std::cout << i << '\n';
  }
}

int main()
{
  //this point is never reached!!?! Hangs before my own code even starts
  std::cout << "start!" << std::endl;
  boost::thread t{thread};
  t.join();
}
```

Comment: Without a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's going to be really hard to say anything.

Comment: the link that I sent "simple thread example" isn't enough? I'll paste the code here then... edit: pasted :)

Comment: once the missing closing quote is added, works fine under clang. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: When running under VS, there is a stop button which interrupts execution. Did you use that and examine the call stack to see if there are any clues?

Comment: @RichardHodges VS2017 with all default settings. DarkFalcon: I had, but before I came in here telling you that I had and found nothing I went ahead and tried again and had another look: noticed that I'm getting a message stating that thread 0x### exited with code 255 and if I just let it sit for a while I get another thread that exists with code 0 (all the while everything is still stuck). Found this other question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605186/program-exe-native-has-exited-with-code-255-0xff) so I'll try to recompile boost and get back to you. Probably only tomorrow. thx

Comment: @DarkFalcon Thanks! I only checked all the debug windows again while trying to give you a full answer and that's when I found the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it to work; I just rebuilt boost and it all works fine now. Must have seem some static/dynamic mix up as mentioned in the question [program.exe: Native' has exited with code 255 (0xff)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605186/program-exe-native-has-exited-with-code-255-0xff).

I rebuilt with the following parameters:

```
b2.exe toolset=msvc-14.1 address-model=32 --build-dir=build\x64 install --prefix="C:\boost" -j4
```

(and then again for 64bit.